# SKPaymentQueue addPayment is throwing an exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have configured my iOS Application's in App purchases in Apple's portal,
I am asking for my products using `SKProductsRequest` and correctly receiving and then storing them in an `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse*)response
{
    NSLog(@"%@", @"AppStore: Accepted");
    for (SKProduct * s in response.products) {
        NSLog(@"    [%@]", s.productIdentifier);
    }

    [productsById removeAllObjects];

    for (SKProduct * product in response.products) {
        [productsById setObject:product forKey:product.productIdentifier];
    }

    [request release];
}
```

However, when trying to make a purchase, the `addPayment` line throws `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'`

```
-(void)purchase:(NSString *)productId {
    SKProduct *selectedProduct = [productsById objectForKey:productId];
    SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct: selectedProduct];
    payment.quantity = 1;

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver: self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment: payment]; //<- this line throws an exception
}
```

I have checked that productId is a valid product and that the payment.quantity is > 0, as apple's documentation says.
I have tried both in the Simulator and in an iPad with the same results.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're not allocating `productsById` dictionary.

Put something like `self.productsById = [@{} mutableCopy];` into your `-viewDidLoad:` method

Comment: I double checked that, just in case, and I think I am allocating it.
I am doing this in the `init` method `productsById = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`

I actually tried removing completely the `productsById` dictionary by calling `addPayment` with an `SKPayment` created from the last object in `response.products` inside the method `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:` with the same results as before. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, the error was not in the parameters of the `SKPaymentQueue addPayment:` message but in the implementation of `SKPaymentQueue paymentQueue: updatedTransactions:`
After printing a stack trace of the exception I noticed that the message was actually being sent to my delegate immediately from `addPayment:`, I never came to see that because the debugger would just run into the exception directly when stepping into `addPayment:` without breaking in my delegate code.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. In my case exception from `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)` was thrown, because I've missed:

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
```

in my `deinit` method.